# SQL Switching output order

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I couldn't find this anywhere and I am having a hard time to fix this.

Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT id, subject, content, description, date, image
FROM articles
WHERE id > $lastid
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 5
```

This give me output in a following order id 11,12,13,14,15.

Is there a way to switch this output so it would be id 15,14,13,12,11?

Comment: Add another query to use this as a subquery and sort the other way.

Comment: Use DESC instead of ASC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id, subject, content, description, date, image FROM articles WHERE id > $lastid
    ORDER BY id ASC
    LIMIT 5
) t
ORDER BY id DESC
```

The [documentations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html) tells you that there are two ways to sort: ascending and descending. The corresponding sql elements are:

- `ORDER BY [Field] ASC` for ascending and
- `ORDER BY [Field] DESC` for descending.

Comment: This give me this output id 20-16 as I got newer articles in DB. Basically I ve got query asking for Newer articles so I grab first article id that was used and ask for articles where id > $firstid

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question. Edited my answer to reflect that

Comment: @VojtěchŠafařík, don't forget to upvote/accept the answer!